# Numpy Selecting all values except two

Tags: python, numpy

I have a bunch of strings in a numpy array and want to select all but two. I am able to do this if its just one string.

```
features = np.array(['F1','F2','F3','F4','F5'])
selected_features = features[features != 'F1']
```

But if its two, this does not work. I've tried passing them in a list and using logical and

```
selected_features = features[features != ['F1','F2']]
```

Any ideas on how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numpy has an own logical and:

```
import numpy as np
 
features = np.array(['F1','F2','F3','F4','F5'])
selected_features = features[np.logical_and(features != 'F1', features != 'F2')]

print(selected_features)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code does not work is what you do by

`selected_features = features[features != ['F1','F2']]`

In plain English, that means picking all the values that are not equal to a list containing ['F1','F2']. Since any of the values of the array is this list, all the values would be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the feature doesn't exist as on **26-June-2020**, which is known as **elementwise comparision**

`selected_features = features[ features != any(['F1','F2'])]`

This is the solution once **numpy** rolls out this feature